# Programatically upload a page in D7

Tags: nodes

I'm certainly a noob, so sorry for this if it's very basic.

I had an installation of D6 and the following code was working perfectly. But when I upgraded to D7, the page was posted, but the body wasn't being uploaded. I see that the location of the body has changed in the MySQL structure, but how do I address it in the code? Here's what was working in D6:

```
    $node->name = rand();
$node->title = $content->title;
$node->created = time();
$node->status = 1; //published
$node->promote = 0;
$node->sticky = 0;
$node->body = $content->data;
$node->type = 'page';
//$node->path = $content->path;
$node->revision = 'true';
node_save($node);
```

Interestingly, when I try to specify the path, the node_save returns an error, but when I specify body, it fires, but the body never shows up.

Can anyone help? I've spent a lot of time on this... much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//Create node
    $node = new StdClass();
    $node->type = 'game';
    $node->title = t('@date-@time', array('@date' => format_date($om__result->date, 'short'), '@time' => format_date($om__result->time, 'custom', "h:i A")));

    //Date
    $node->field_date = array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => format_date($om__result->date, 'short'),
      ),
    );

    //Location
    $node->field_location = array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => $om__result->location,
      ),
    );


    //Home team
    $node->field_home = array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => $om__result->home,
      ),
    );

    //Visitor
    $node->field_away = array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => $om__result->visitor,
      ),
    );

    //Division
    $node->field_divsion = array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => $om__result->divisoin,
      ),
    );

    //Program
    $node->field_program = array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => $om__result->program,
      ),
    );

    //Time
    $node->field_time = array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => $om__result->time,
      ),
    );

    //Field
    $node->field_number = array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => $om__result->field_nuber,
      ),
    );

    node_submit($node);
    node_save($node);
    drupal_set_message(t('@node has been created', array('@node' => $node->title)));
?>
```

Comment: In which way does this help the OP?

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, there is one thing that changes: The node body is now a field created with the Field API. As consequence, the code should be changed to something similar to the following code.

```
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->type = 'article';
  node_object_prepare($node);

  $node->title = $content->title;
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;

  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value']   = $content->data;
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['summary'] = text_summary($content->data);

  // [1]
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['format']  = 'filtered_html';

  $node->path = array('alias' => $content->path);

  node_save($node);
```

The other node properties you are setting are set by [node_object_prepare()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_object_prepare/7). The line I commented with `[1]` is setting the input format to "Filtered HTML"; if you want to set a different input format for the node, [filter_formats()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!filter!filter.module/function/filter_formats/7) returns information about the currently enabled input formats, including the input format ID to use with `$node->body[$node->language][0]['format']`.